# ASP.NET Core JWT authorization failing with "AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated"

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, f#, jwt, fable-f#

I'm trying to set up JWT authentication in my F# ASP.NET Core + Fable project, and I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

Here are some snippets of the important server-side parts.

API model for Fable.Remoting:

```ml
type PublicApi = {
    TryLogIn: string * string -> Async<Result<SecurityToken, string>>
    LogOut: unit -> Async<unit>
}

type AccountApi = {
    GetMyAccountDetails: unit -> Async<MyAccount>
    TryGetAccountDetails: string -> Async<Account option>
}

type Apis = {
    pub: PublicApi
    account: AccountApi
}

type ApiFactory = unit -> Apis
```

Token generation:

```ml
open System
open System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
open System.Security.Claims
open System.Text
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.Options
open Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
open Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens

let jwtAppIdentity = "http://example-app.com"

let getJwtEncryptionKeyText (config: IConfiguration) = config.GetRequiredSection("AppSettings")["JwtEncryptionKey"]
let getJwtEncryptionKey config =
    let keyText = getJwtEncryptionKeyText config
    keyText |> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes |> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey

let generateJwtToken email config =
    let claims = [|
        Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, email)
        Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    |]
    
    let expires = Nullable (DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours 1.0)
    let notBefore = Nullable (DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes -1.0)
    let key = getJwtEncryptionKey config
    let signingCredentials = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(key = key, algorithm = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
    
    JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer = jwtAppIdentity,
        audience = jwtAppIdentity,
        claims = claims,
        expires = expires,
        notBefore = notBefore,
        signingCredentials = signingCredentials)
```

Giraffe app:

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open System.Reflection
open System.Security.Claims
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Fable.Remoting.Server
open Fable.Remoting.Giraffe
open FSharp.Logf
open Giraffe
open Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
let authorize = requiresAuthentication (challenge JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

let webApp : HttpHandler =
    choose [
        createApi (fun ctx -> ApiProvider.makePublicApi (ctx.GetService<IConfiguration>()) (ctx.GetService<IDataProvider>())) |> Remoting.buildHttpHandler
        authorize >=> (createApi (fun ctx -> ApiProvider.makeAccountApi ctx.User (ctx.GetService<IDataProvider>())) |> Remoting.buildHttpHandler)
        authorize >=> route "/whoami" >=> whoamiHandler
        
        setStatusCode 404 >=> text "Not Found" ]
```

`configureApp` and `configureServices`:

```ml
type Dummy = Dummy
let configureApp (ctx: WebHostBuilderContext) (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    let ml = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<obj>>()
    logfi ml "ContentRoot: %s{webRoot}" (ctx.Configuration.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey))
    logfi ml "WebRoot: %s{webRoot}" (ctx.Configuration.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.WebRootKey))
    
    let env = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>()
    let builder =
        match env.IsDevelopment() with
        | true  ->
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
        | false ->
            app .UseGiraffeErrorHandler(errorHandler)
                .UseHttpsRedirection()
    
    builder
        .UseCors(configureCors env)
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseAuthorization()
        .UseFileServer()
        .UseGiraffe(webApp)

let configureServices (ctx: WebHostBuilderContext) (services : IServiceCollection) =
    services
        .AddOptions()
        .AddCors()
        |> ignore
    
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(fun options ->
            options.TokenValidationParameters <- TokenValidationParameters(
                // temporarily set to false to get it working at all
                ValidateActor = false, //true,
                ValidateAudience = false, //true,
                ValidateLifetime = false, //true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Token.jwtAppIdentity,
                ValidAudience = Token.jwtAppIdentity,
                IssuerSigningKey = Token.getJwtEncryptionKey ctx.Configuration
            )
        ) |> ignore
    
    services
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddSingleton<SessionizerDbContext>(Func<IServiceProvider,SessionizerDbContext>(fun isp ->
            let connString = getConnectionString (isp.GetService<IConfiguration>())
            let dbCtx = new SessionizerDbContext(new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
            dbCtx.Connection.Open ()
            dbCtx
        ))
        .AddScoped<IDataProvider>(Func<IServiceProvider,_>(fun isp -> DataProvider(isp.GetService<SessionizerDbContext>())))
        .AddGiraffe()
        .AddSingleton<ILogger>(Func<IServiceProvider,ILogger>(fun isp -> isp.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger()))
        .AddSingleton<Dummy>(fun isp ->
            upgradeDatabase (isp.GetService<ILogger>()) (getConnectionString ctx.Configuration)
            Dummy
        ) |> ignore
```

Client-side Token and API creation:

```ml
type SecurityToken = { value: string }

let makeApi (token: SecurityToken option) =
    let withAuthHeaderIfSome api =
        match token with
        | Some t -> api |> Remoting.withAuthorizationHeader t.value
        | None -> api
    {
        pub = Remoting.createApi () |> withAuthHeaderIfSome |> Remoting.withRouteBuilder apiV1RouteBuilder |> Remoting.buildProxy<PublicApi>
        account = Remoting.createApi () |> withAuthHeaderIfSome |> Remoting.withRouteBuilder apiV1RouteBuilder |> Remoting.buildProxy<AccountApi>
    }
```

I've set up the pipelines in accordance with what all the examples do, and the client gets a valid token, yet when I try to use it to authenticate the client, the server 401's me. In the logs, the only relevant log lines say `AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.` and `AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.`. Here's part of one of the logs, with verbose logging:

```
2023-03-13 22:51:49.444 -06:00 [DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
2023-03-13 22:51:49.444 -06:00 [DBG] POST requests are not supported
2023-03-13 22:51:49.449 -06:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HMP48V4QH8TB", Request id "0HMP48V4QH8TB:00000003": started reading request body.
2023-03-13 22:51:49.449 -06:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HMP48V4QH8TB", Request id "0HMP48V4QH8TB:00000003": done reading request body.
2023-03-13 22:51:50.124 -06:00 [DBG] Giraffe returned Some for HTTP/1.1 POST at /api/v1/PublicApi/TryLogIn in 679.867375
2023-03-13 22:51:50.125 -06:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HMP48V4QH8TB" completed keep alive response.
2023-03-13 22:51:50.125 -06:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1/PublicApi/TryLogIn application/json;+charset=utf-8 53 - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 683.5235ms
2023-03-13 22:51:50.137 -06:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/AccountApi/GetMyAccountDetails application/json;+charset=utf-8 -
2023-03-13 22:51:50.137 -06:00 [VRB] All hosts are allowed.
2023-03-13 22:51:50.137 -06:00 [DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
2023-03-13 22:51:50.137 -06:00 [DBG] The request path /api/v1/AccountApi/GetMyAccountDetails does not match a supported file type
2023-03-13 22:51:50.137 -06:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
2023-03-13 22:51:50.137 -06:00 [DBG] Giraffe returned Some for HTTP/1.1 GET at /api/v1/AccountApi/GetMyAccountDetails in 0.184166
2023-03-13 22:51:50.138 -06:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HMP48V4QH8TB" completed keep alive response.
2023-03-13 22:51:50.138 -06:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/AccountApi/GetMyAccountDetails application/json;+charset=utf-8 - - 401 0 - 1.0892ms
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the server-side code is actually not the problem - if you try it out in Postman with an authorization header using the token returned from the login endpoint, the server happily serves up a `200 OK`.

The problem is on the client side. You need to prepend `Bearer`  (with a space) to the token string:

```ml
api |> Remoting.withAuthorizationHeader ("Bearer " + t.value)
```

It is just surprising that the server gives such a vague and unhelpful error message.